# Is it possible to create a procedural spiral around a tube?

Tags: materials

I have been struggling to create a bump that goes spiraling around a tube, sort of like a toilet paper tube.

Basically, it is a line that wraps around the tube several times, continuously.

I cannot figure out the math to make it happen.

Comment: Please define you question further. Is the spiral answer what you asked for? Or do you want a spiraling bump map?

Comment: After i read the answer from @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ-ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ i realized that even my second idea did not fit the question, thus i deleted my answer, as I believe his answer should be on point. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4):

I've googled one [BlenderArtists solution](https://blenderartists.org/t/radial-gradient-past-one-revolution/1145168/2), that also works reasonably well for a tube.
All credits to [PyBlend](https://blenderartists.org/u/PyBlend)

You can use an Empty to control it.
Otherwise it uses object's origin point.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ totally answered it. I have added three control values to make it a little more customizable for my needs. Here's my node group, based off of their excellent work!

[image]