# How to create spiral in blender?

Tags: node-editor, faces, procedural

I have attach 2 images of what I'm trying to achieve...

[image]
[image]

I would like to know how to do this stuff by nodes or by random faces selection... I tried inset faces and rotate some vertice but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You mean a spiral mesh or a procedural texture?

Comment: First spiral done with nodes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/107656/78972. Second spiral using nodes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/166707/78972

Answer (score 2):

Here is a node tree to create a spiral from a Wave texture. It takes generated texture coordinates, splits them, and [converts them to polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) with the atan2 node and the Pythagorean theorem. It then adds the coordinates together so that the texture rotates as you get away from the center.

The Greater Than node acts as a threshold, to have a clear separation between black and white.

To change the direction and rotation speed, you can tweak the light grey Multiply node in the center. Value is the rotation speed; sign is the direction.

[image: A node tree to create a spiral from a Wave texture.]